# Why I cannot connect 2 computers using different network

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, voip

I am experimenting TCP/IP Voice Chat application (I know that TCP/IP is a terrible idea for voice chat, but just want to understand the mechanic). I found this website (http://www.socketcoder.com/ArticleFile.aspx?ArticleID=73) that provide a C# project which does so.

Then, I tried connecting two computers together in the same network (same router, SSID; internal IP used), it works. But, when tried with different networks and used external IP, it just doesn't work.

So, I wonder why two different networks cause this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a networking question, as you are using an external IP address I am going to assume that the server and client are sitting behind a NAT and/or firewall.

Before looking deeper into the code, first check if the client can reach the server on the required port. A good test method is to use telnet to connect to the server on said port. To see what a successful connection looks like, first run the same test locally (some messages that success look like failures if you don't have a keen eye).

Assuming this is the issue, you will need to setup a port forwarding rule on the servers internet router and allow the port on any firewalls.

Comment: I've disabled firewall. But I'll try port forwarding, thanks.